# A Flask-WTF form that does not send an email when the user submit the form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I decided to follow this tutorial([https://www.boxcontrol.net/adding-contact-form-to-your-site-using-flask-and-python3.html](http://www.boxcontrol.net/adding-contact-form-to-your-site-using-flask-and-python3.html)) but create a different type of form where the user inputs their personal information and the submitted form is emailed to my G-mail account. However after submitting the form I receivce no email or error.
The first thing I did was to create ContactForm class.

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

class ContactForm(Form):
  name = TextField("Fullname", validators=[InputRequired('Please enter your name.')])
  email = TextField("Email",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter your email address.")])
  NoChildren = TextField("Number of children dependants (if applicable):",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  NoAdults = TextField("Number of adult dependants (if applicable):",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  travel = TextField("Will you be travelling alone?",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  marriage = TextField("What is your marital status?",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  nation = TextField("Current nationality(ies):",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  dob = TextField("Date of birth:",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  phone = TextField("Phone number:",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  nonukaddress = TextField("Your current non-UK address:",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  ukaddress = TextField("UK address:",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  history = TextField("Do you have any criminal history?",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  hadvisa = TextField("Have you ever had any other visas?",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  refusevisa = TextField("Have you been refused a visa before?",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  medical = TextField("Did you receive any medical treatment in the UK?",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  letter = TextField("Do you have a letter from a UK regulated financial institution confirming that original evidence of funds has been supplied?",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  sole = TextField("Are you the sole owner of the money?",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a subject.")])
  additional = TextAreaField("Additional information/questions/requests:",  validators=[InputRequired("Please enter a message.")])
  submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

Then I created the HTML template for my form.

```
{% block content %}
  <h2>Contact</h2>

  {% if success %}
    <p>Thank you for your message. We'll get back to you shortly.</p>

  {% else %}  
    {% for message in form.name.errors %}
      <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for message in form.email.errors %}
      <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method=post>
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

      {{ form.name.label }}
      {{ form.name }}

      {{ form.email.label }}
      {{ form.email }}

      {{ form.NoChildren.label }}
      {{ form.NoChildren }}

      {{ form.travel.label }}
      {{ form.travel }}

      {{ form.marriage.label }}
      {{ form.marriage }}

      {{ form.nation.label }}
      {{ form.nation }}

      {{ form.dob.label }}
      {{ form.dob }}

      {{ form.phone.label }}
      {{ form.phone }}

      {{ form.nonukaddress.label }}
      {{ form.nonukaddress }}

      {{ form.ukaddress.label }}
      {{ form.ukaddress }}

      {{ form.history.label }}
      {{ form.history }}

      {{ form.hadvisa.label }}
      {{ form.hadvisa }}

      {{ form.refusevisa.label }}
      {{ form.refusevisa }}

      {{ form.parents.label }}
      {{ form.parents }}

      {{ form.medical.label }}
      {{ form.medical }}

      {{ form.letter.label }}
      {{ form.letter }}

      {{ form.sole.label }}
      {{ form.sole }}

      {{ form.ukbank.label }}
      {{ form.ukbank }}

      {{ form.additional.label }}
      {{ form.additional }}

      {{ form.submit }}
    </form> 
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

My main flask file looks like this.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from forms import ContactForm
from flask_mail import Message, Mail
import os

mail = Mail()

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'development key'

app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 465
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = 'your_email@example.com'
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = '*******'

mail.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
  form = ContactForm()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
      flash('All fields are required.')
      return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:
      msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='contact@example.com', recipients=['your_email@example.com'])
      msg.body = """
      From:%s <%s>,
            %s
            """ % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data,form.NoChildren.data,form.travel.data,form.marriage.data, form.nation.data, form.dob.data, form.phone.data, form.nonukaddress.data, form.ukaddress.data, form.history.data, form.hadvisa.data, form.refusevisa.data, form.parents.data, form.medical.data,  form.letter.data, form.sole.data, form.ukbank.data, form.additional.data)
      mail.send(msg)

      return render_template('contact.html', success=True)

  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down— at the moment you have a lot of moving parts. If you're not getting an error, my initial thought would be that your emails are getting sent to junk/spam.

If you create a new view that just sends a static email, does it work?

```
@app.route('/testemail')
def send_test_email():
    msg = Message('Title',sender='you@yours.com', recipients=['you@yours.com'])
    msg.body('Hello...')
    mail.send(msg)
```

If it doesn't-- then you know the problem relates to your email side of your code, then you can start looking into the `MAIL_DEBUG` options available in `Flask-Mail`, checking spam folders etc.

Generally you might find it easier and more reliable to use services like that handle email delivery for you, rather then sending SMTP requests yourself, you use their Python library to send them your email data, then they take care of the rest. I personally use [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) but there are a myriad of companies that provide a similar service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not receiving any errors and no email is being sent, set `MAIL_DEBUG=True`. Flask-Mail uses the `smtplib` module which can [set](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-mail/blob/master/flask_mail.py#L153) debug level. Also try updating `config` before initializing mail.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(dict(
    DEBUG = True,
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com',
    MAIL_PORT = 587,
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True,
    MAIL_USE_SSL = False,
    MAIL_USERNAME = 'my_username@gmail.com',
    MAIL_PASSWORD = 'my_password',
))

mail = Mail(app)
```

See [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/85/).